# SqlAzureDacpacDeployment yaml queries

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, dacpac

I have inherited a YAML file for dacpac deployment. the first part of the DB section uses SqlAzureDacpacDeployment like this :

```
task: SqlAzureDacpacDeployment@1
  displayName: 'Generate CL-${{ parameters.environmentDisplayName }} SQL Migration Script'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: ##
    authenticationType: ##
    serverName: ##
    databaseName: ##
    sqlUsername: ##
    sqlPassword:##
    deployType: **DacpacTask**
    deploymentAction: **Script**
    dacpacFile: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/Database/ContentLibrary.dacpac
```

which gets the dacpac file and then makes a tsql script from it. So I presume the sql script which is required to build the DB Schema

and then there is a 2nd yaml section like this :

```
- task: SqlAzureDacpacDeployment@1
  displayName: 'Deploy CL-${{ parameters.environmentDisplayName }} SQL Migration Script'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: ##
    authenticationType: ##
    serverName: ##
    databaseName: ##
    sqlUsername: ##
    sqlPassword: ##
    deployType: **DacpacTask**
    deploymentAction: **Publish**
    dacpacFile: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/Database_Migration_${{ parameters.environmentDisplayName }}/ContentLibrary.dacpac
```

Then this one should public the tsql onto the target and create stuff if need be or plaining update the bits needed.

What it does is just overwrite whats already there, so if there is a schema there already then all the constraints will kick in a cause a lot of errors.

how do i go about ammending this code so that it does either an update (to make the db upto date with the dacpac or create the full thing if needed and not just overwrite when stuff is already there) ?

Is it because of the locations of the file ? i.e the DacpacFile seciton in each pieces of code ?

Answer (score 1):

Are the constraints in the SQL databases are named dynamically (i.e. define without names ) or they are added with static names in the table definition - if they are not named then update using sqlpackage.exe and DACPAC tries to drop and recreate them.

If you can not define them in tables then you can add option for not dropping them  /p:DropConstraintsNotInSource=False

**ref:** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlpackage/sqlpackage-publish?view=sql-server-ver15